# CanCan singleton loading with pluralized class name

Tags: cancan

I'm currently experiencing an issue with the latest version of CanCan.  It seems that the gem won't load singleton resources with pluralized names.

```
class Preferences < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'preferences'
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :preferences
end

#controller
class PreferencesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user! #from Devise

  load_and_authorize_resource :singleton => true,
                              :through => :current_user,
                              :through_association => :preferences,
                              :parent => false
end

#ability.rb
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    can [:read, :update], Preferences, :user_id => user.id
  end
end
```

I keep getting an error like this when I run my controller spec:

```
Failures:

 1) PreferencesController GET #show should return http success
     Failure/Error: get :show
     NameError:
       uninitialized constant Preference
     # ./spec/controllers/preferences_controller_spec.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

It seems no matter what combination of `load_resource` arguments I try, I can't get my specs to pass again without reverting back to loading the resource manually like this:

```
class PreferencesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def show
    @preferences = current_user.preferences
    authorize! :read, @preferences
  end
end
```

Is there some magic combination of `load_and_authorize_resource` parameters I need to use?  I have this same configuration working in another singleton controller where the resource falls under normal Rails conventions (i.e. User has_one :profile), so I know this works already under normal situations.

Comment: I also shared this issue in the CanCan Issue tracker for a related issue.  https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/452